# Jquery .Change and .load together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping to update one text box when another changes using jquery. Here's what I have:

```
$('#inputs').change(function() {
    var first_name=$(".first_name").val();
    var last_name=$(".last_name").val();
    var username=$(".username").val();
    var category=$(".category").val();
    if ((!empty(first_name))&&(!empty(last_name))&&(!empty(username))&&(category!="empty")) {
      form1.process.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
      form1.process.disabled = true;
    }
    $('.tweet').load('ajax.php?first='+first_name+'&last='+last_name+'&username='+username+'&category='+category);
});
```

yet nothing is coming up. Ajax.php (Don't ask why its called that) is fine.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are these input types if so why not post them?

Comment: Also is it called Ajax.php not ajax.php linux servers can be very picky about it

Comment: because they're not submitted. The idea is after a change, the other text box updates

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an `empty` method.

Comment: ah that is another error, but a while ago I commented out that section and it was the same

Comment: What is `form1.process`?

Comment: What does Ajax.php return? and my point about being submitted is that jquery can post it Async so no urls that are easy to modify :).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the `?` in `ajax.php?first=...`. Your URL to ajax.php is broken, regardless if the page itself works.

Comment: sorry typo, but the & are missing. no difference

Comment: Are you saying adding the `?` and `&` didn't fix it?